# Which is a better NAS : Synology DS216+II or QNap TS251+

Tags: nas

I am looking for a Nas for home use.

**my needs :**

- data Storage (Photos, Videos, Etc.)
- Multimedia server (streaming, Music)
- Surveillance station (communication with cameras)

I've been searching for a couple of weeks and now i am hesitating between two brands : Synology and QNap and precisely two NAS : the [Synology DS216+II](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS216+II) and the [QNap TS251+](https://www.qnap.com/en/product/model.php?II=195)

The QNap Hardware looks more interesting : 2GB RAM upgradable to 8GB, Quad Core CPU, the Synology 1GB RAM not upgradable and dual core CPU.
Both NAS have almost the same price.

It will be my first Nas so i don't have any experience with none of the two brands.

Which product meets my needs and has better reliability?

Comment: If you are not looking for portability, you could always build your own using an mATX board/chassis/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multimedia streaming, beware of the qnap.  They have recently removed Kodi support due to (apparently) licensing issues with Dolby.  Further, their default player (again due to the licensing issue) will not play or transcode ac3 or dts.  I'm not sure that you can even play an mkv.  Lots of unhappy people on their forums at the moment.  I had the same(ish) choice as you: ds216+ii or ts-251a.  I went with the 251a because of better harware and assumed support for the most popular audio formats and container.  I regret that decision and will likely return it in favour of the 216+ii.

Comment: I think I ll consider putting more money to go for the synology ds716+II

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced with both NAS, I would recommend you only QNAP.

Easy to setup VPN, SSL and Multimedia with your own domains.

Also, done speed test on the network from QNAP to Mac sent 1GB data:

1.QNAP: 432MB download and 345MB upload

2.SYS:  180MB download and 190MB Upload

Answer (score 0):

Both Nas can do the things you listed pretty well.
And since they are at the same price, I would probably choose Qnap with better HW specs. More important thing is that TS-251+ has HDMI that makes it a great multimedia server, you can easily stream videos to TV.

Answer (score 0):

Qnap will run Plex *pretty perfectly* -- takes care of the format concerns. The machine itself can transcode on the fly or as a backround task too. Plus DNLA support.

I also am pretty sure Kodi is available through qnapclub.eu Also Sickcbeard and some other fun stuff.

Surveillance station works like a charm but the new QVRpro is pretty sick. You can upload maps and the camera support is easy - as is assigning storage space. What can I say -- I'm a fan with a love/hate relationship with Qnap.

I hate their "tech support". They just yell at you. lol